CSS animation-timeline: view() / scrolling not working
I have a page (created with bootstrap studio) with a few sections, if i test it on my section itself it works when it comes to view, but i have a row with 2 colums in that section, when i try it with my colum it doesnt work. Maybe i do something wrong? .... the section is in my body tag.
When it is like this, the colum background is green from beginning, and doesent change color, however i scroll and where the view is.
This is html:
    <section id="aufspur" class="text-center content-section" style="background: url('index-transformed.jpeg') center / cover no-repeat;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-lg-4 offset-xl-0 mx-auto test" style="background: rgb(255,205,27);border-radius: 12px;box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">
                <h1 style="color: rgb(0,0,0);font-family: Futura;font-size: 50px;margin-top: 30px;">auf spur</h1>
                <p style="font-family: Futura;font-size: 18px;margin-bottom: 0;"><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">This is my TEXT 1</span><br /><br /><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">TEXT 2</span><br /><br /></p>
                <p style="font-family: Futura;font-size: 18px;margin-bottom: 0;"><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">TEXT 3</span><br /><br /></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

This is my css:
.test {
  animation: fadeInTest linear forwards;
  animation-timeline: view(250px);
}

@keyframes fadeInTest {
  from {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  to {
    background-color: green;
  }
}

EDIT:
Ok i found out that my section has already an "animation", it is the parallax-bg. When i turn it of it works.
Is it possible that my backgroud image has the effect and i can do other stuff within the section?

You are missing the closing section tag. Maybe this is the issue? Or it is missing because of copy&paste?
When I try to recreate a minimal scenario of your code, it seems to work just fine:


/* --- for demo --- */

main {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

section {
  margin: 300px 0;
}


/* --- */

.test {
  animation: fadeInTest linear forwards;
  animation-timeline: view(250px);
}

@keyframes fadeInTest {
  from {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  to {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<main>
  scroll
  <section id="aufspur" class="text-center content-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-lg-4 offset-xl-0 mx-auto test">
          <h1>auf spur</h1>
          <p>
            This is my TEXT 1 <br> TEXT 2
          </p>
          <p>TEXT 3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>




No it was just bad copy and paste :-(
i tried also only the h1 in the colum, dont work, then i wrapped all in an extra div and tried... dont work. It works only on the section itself :-(
everythig outside the section or the section itself, works... tries another div outside the section, works just fine

... and the strange thing is, that it is somehow working, because the state, in this test, the backgound color is green, from the beginning.
